# Scheduled posts: set default time?

Tags: scheduled-posts

I want to be able to set the default time in the options for a Scheduled Post to be a specific time of the day, as opposed to it defaulting to the current time. Is there a plugin or some code I can add/tweak to accomplish this? I was unable to find anything here or on Google to do this.

Comment: I just released a plugin that will help you with that: [Automatic Post Date Filler](http://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-post-date-filler/)

Comment: Wow, this looks like an excellent plugin! Installing it now. Thanks for the plugin and the heads up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin [Automatic Post Date Filler](http://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-post-date-filler/) suggested in the comments is a perfect solution. Even better than imagined with all the various preferences to how it dynamically sets up the defaults when you edit the scheduled time.

Answer (score 0):

```
function set_default_publish_time($data, $postarr)
{
    if ($data['post_status']==='draft' || $data['post_status']==='auto-draft') {
        $default_publish_time = date('Y-m-d 06:00:00');
        $data['post_date'] = $default_publish_time;
        $data['post_date_gmt'] = get_gmt_from_date($default_publish_time);
    }
    return $data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'set_default_publish_time', 99, 2);
```

should do the job, it sets the default time to 6 AM.